# Evaluate the integral $\int_{0}^{10} 2^x dx$ using the limit definition

Tags: integration

How do I evaluate a the integral $\int_{0}^{10} 2^x dx$ using the limit definition of an integral? We can get the values:
$\Delta x = \frac{10-0}{n}$  and $f(\frac{10i}{n}) = 2^{\frac{10i}{n}}$, thus setting up

$$\int_{0}^{10} 2^x dx = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{10}{n} 2^{\frac{10i}{n}}$$ However, I am unable to evaluate this to get a value.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives some expression. Maybe you can use L'Hopital's rule after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

This is a geometric progression with common ratio $2^{\frac{10}{n}}$. Use $$\sum_{i=1}^n r^i =\frac{r(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the sum. We can factor out the $10/n$ to get
$$I_n=\frac{10}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}2^{\frac{10k}{n}}$$
This is a sum of a [geometric sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series) so
$$I_n=\frac{10}{n}\frac{2^{\frac{10(n+1)}{n}}-1}{2^{\frac{10}{n}}-1}$$
So then,
$$I=\lim_{n\to \infty} I_n = \lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{10}{n}\frac{2^{\frac{10(n+1)}{n}}-1}{2^{\frac{10}{n}}-1}$$
$$=(2^{10}-1)\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{10}{n(2^{\frac{10}{n}}-1)}$$
It is a good exercise to check that this is equal to
$$I=\frac{2^{10}-1}{\ln(2)}.$$
Note that this aligns with the result obtained by direct integration.

Answer (score -1):

Wolfram Alpha gives this expression.

$$-\frac{5115 \cdot 2^{10/n + 1}}{(n - n \cdot 2^{10/n})}$$

Maybe one can use L'Hopital's rule after that to solve the limit... because the limit itself does not look very straightforward to solve.